# Applying a css rule on a list of checkbox button options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have an object having a list of items. I want to display them as checkbox buttons. I am using the following snippet of the code to generate the radio buttons. They are working fine.

```
for (var i = 0; i < mObject.removeList.length; i++) {
    //Todo add logic of checkbox here
    var lineBreak = "";
    if ((i+1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        lineBreak = "<br />";
    }

    $('#' + listsDiv + 'RemoveList').append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + mObject.removeList[i].ItemName + '" value="' + mObject.removeList[i].ItemName + '" />' + mObject.removeList[i].ItemName + lineBreak);
}
```

The problem is I want to display them 3 per row and distributed evenly in a row. I have managed to divide them in rows of three, but I cant get my head around making them styled in three columns every line. If I use css for adding a margin-right on checkboxes they are spearated but not evenly aligned in columns because of the length of the text of checkbox.

I was hoping to find a CSS solution for making them display in rows of 3 columns with alignment of each checkbox to the left of their respective column.

The number of items is unknown in the list.

Currently, this css does not give the required output.

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to wrap all the checkboxes in `label` elements. You can then apply `width: 33%` to those labels, and they will automatically fill three rows in any container.

The other advantage of using `label` elements is that they increase the hit area of the checkbox, so you can now click the text associated with the input to check it as well.

Try this:

```js
var mObject = {
  removeList: [
      { ItemName: 'Foo1' },
      { ItemName: 'Foo2' },
      { ItemName: 'Foo3' },
      { ItemName: 'Foo4' },
      { ItemName: 'Foo5' },
      { ItemName: 'Foo6' },
      { ItemName: 'Foo7' },
      { ItemName: 'Foo8' }
    ]
}

for (var i = 0; i < mObject.removeList.length; i++) {
    var itemName = mObject.removeList[i].ItemName;
    // Note the <label> wrapper here...
    $('#RemoveList').append('<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + itemName + '" value="' + itemName + '" />' + itemName + '</label>');
}
```

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="RemoveList"></div>
```

You can also simplify the loop if you're able to target browsers that support ES2015, by using a `forEach()`, like this:

```
mObject.removeList.forEach(function(o) {
    var itemName = o.ItemName;
    $('#RemoveList').append('<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + itemName + '" value="' + itemName + '" />' + itemName + '</label>');
})
```

Comment: So it does not need the line break ?

Comment: No, not at all. It breaks automatically when the width of the labels exceeds that of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in divs like

```
$('#' + listsDiv + 'RemoveList').append('<div class="col"><input type="checkbox" name="' + mObject.removeList[i].ItemName + '" value="' + mObject.removeList[i].ItemName + '" />' + mObject.removeList[i].ItemName + lineBreak + "</div>");
```

Then give it 33% width and `text-align`, `padding`, etc. if you want.

```
col{
    width: 33%;
}
```